# Rails 4 mysql2 error when deploying to production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, yaml, digital-ocean

I've got an Ubuntu virtual server (Digital Ocean Droplet) set up with Capistrano 3. I've successfully gotten all of the directories set up and the project directory has the current folder in it, containing `config/database.yml` file. I can't get it deployed to where it will run. It gets stuck on the `rake db:migrate` phase. `rake assets:precompile` successfully works, so I think it must be something with my `database.yml` file. The "production" block looks like this:

**config/database.yml** (production part)

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: capstone_production
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: localhost
  port: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I have checked that the file is valid YAML with YAMLLint utility. Also, the environment variables echo properly with (root) credentials that I am able to use for mysql login. When I run `cap production deploy:check`, everything is good. However, running `cap production deploy` does everything okay until it gets to the `rake db:migrate` Capistrano process. Then it aborts and throws up this:

```
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 107.170.105.223: Exception while executing on host 107.170.105.223: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `new'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `up'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:792:in `migrate'
/home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/rails-331210df7c8a/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written
```

I've tried many combinations of YAML syntax and restarted mysql server, puma server, and NGINX server over and over again. This is crazy, please help.

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to stem from this:

```
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

From what I've read in MySQL docs, this error is thrown when you try to login without password. So I've got all the right credentials - I can even hard code the actual username and password into the YAML file and same error. For some reason when Capistrano executes the following command (via cap production deploy or cap production deploy:migrate), **it's not including the password** from database.yml:

```
INFO [85893e95] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate on 107.170.105.223
DEBUG [85893e95] Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/capstone_project/releases/20160205235633 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate )
```

How to ensure that Capistrano executes the migration just like I would locally in development?

Thank you

Comment: try to write `mysql -u root -p password` on droplet terminal (connect via ssh to it) and describe the result.

Comment: @ProgNoob Thanks for the reply! That particular command asks for the root password and throws an error. Where `password` is located in that statement it expects a database name to use. When I log in to mysql normally in this fashion, I use `mysql -u root -p`. It then prompts for password. I enter the password and welcomed with `mysql>' prompt.